# Expanding variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within a for loop (i.e. `.each()`), I need to set the variable of openvalue to 1 if a condition is met. I then need to access the value of this variable at the end of the loop. Regardless of the situation, when I print the variable to the console, the result is always 0. I know why (variable scope), but I'm wondering how I can modify my code so that if openvalue is set to 1 within the forloop, that value will have permanence outside of the forloop.

```
var openvalue = 0; //sets default value
textinputs.each(function () {
    var attr = $(this).attr('disabled');
    if (attr == undefined || attr == false) {
        var openvalue = 1; // if there is an input that is not disabled, set this value to 1
    }
});
console.log(openvalue);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you declare a new variable with the same name.  Instead, you want to assign a value to the already declared variable.  So, "openvalue = 1" instead of "var openvalue = 1":

```
var openvalue = 0; //sets default value
textinputs.each(function () {
var attr = $(this).attr('disabled');
if (attr == undefined || attr == false) {
    openvalue = 1; // if there is an input that is not disabled, set this value to 1
}
});

console.log(openvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists only because you redeclare your `openvalue` variable with a `var` statement, which creates a second `openvalue` variable in the new function scope.  Here is your code in a snippet below:

```js
var openvalue = 0; //sets default value
var textinputs = $('input');
textinputs.each(function () {
    var attr = $(this).attr('disabled');
    if (attr == undefined || attr == false) {
        var openvalue = 1; // if there is an input that is not disabled, set this value to 1
    }
});
console.log(openvalue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input disabled />
<input />
```

Here in our solution we omit the second declaration and simply refer to the original `openvalue` in the parent scope, and we get the expected behavior:

```js
var openvalue = 0; //sets default value
var textinputs = $('input');
textinputs.each(function () {
    var attr = $(this).attr('disabled');
    if (attr == undefined || attr == false) {
        openvalue = 1; // if there is an input that is not disabled, set this value to 1
    }
});
console.log(openvalue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input disabled />
<input />
```